# collect2.exe: error: 1d returned 1 exits status

Tags: c++11

I am coding in c++ on SublimeText3 and using the command window in the folder to manually compile it and run it but when i try compile it using

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 TheThirdTask.cpp -o TheThirdTask
```

(TheThirdTask.cpp is the name of the file, see code below) it comes up with

```
c:/mingnw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../libmmingwex.a(vsnprintf.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of ʽvsnprintf'
C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5MFRJe.o:TheThirdTask.cpp:(.text$vsnprintf[_vsnprintf]+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: 1d returned 1 exit status
```

I am fairly new to coding, I only started when I started varsity at the beginning of the year so I have no idea what it is tell me. Please help, this is for a very important assignment.

TheThirdTask.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int b;
    int val;
    int rem;
    int currentVal;
    string result;

    cin >> b;
    cin >> val;

    while(val != -1){   
        currentVal = val;

        do{

             rem = currentVal%b;

            if(rem > 9){
                char c = rem;
                c = c + 55;

                result = c + result;
                currentVal = floor(currentVal/b);
            }
            else{
                result = to_string(rem) + result;
                currentVal = floor(currentVal/b);
            }

        }while(currentVal != 0);

        cout << result << endl;
        cin >> val;
        rem = 0;
        currentVal = 0;
        result = "";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really use the shown command line to build your program? Because as shown you would get errors before the compilation even started (it is `-pedantic` with one `n`, and `-std=c++11`). When writing text like commands or code, the copy-paste it to get it right. Error you add while writing the question distracts from your actual problem. Please edit your question to correct the command.

Comment: And by the way, why are you using the floating-point `floor` function using the result of an integer division? The integer division will already truncate the result. E.g. `3 / 2` is equal to `1`, no `floor` call needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MinGW g++: Multiple definition of vsnprintf when using to\_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294488/mingw-g-multiple-definition-of-vsnprintf-when-using-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

how about trying out 2 separate commands

try

```
g++ -Wall -c TheThirdTask.cpp
```

and then

```
g++ TheThirdTask.o
```

The above steps should create a binary with the default name

or just go with

```
g++ -o YourBinaryName TheThirdTask.cpp
```

***for C++ 11***

```
$ g++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic TheThirdTask.cpp -o mybinary
```

Comment: this doesn't work because the to_string function is only defined in c++11 so i need to compile it in terms of c++11, also i apologize about the spelling errors but i did type it in the command window correctly.

Comment: updated my answer for C++ 11. Recommend removing older versions of gcc and then reinstalling the version you plan to use