# MinGW g++: Multiple definition of vsnprintf when using to_string

Tags: windows, c++11, gcc, g++, mingw

I just started using MinGW for Windows. When trying to create executable using

`g++ a.cpp -o a.exe -std=c++14`

for the code below:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x = to_string(123);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting following error:

```
C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../libmingwex.a(vsnprintf.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of vsnprintf
C:\Users\..\Local\Temp\cc4sJDvK.o:c:/mingw/include/stdio.h:426: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the root cause for this error and how can I make it go away? While I can easily find a replacement for `to_string()` function I'm not sure what is causing this error to occur in the first place.

Comment: Sounds like your MinGW installation is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue using [MinGW w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) compiler

1. download mingw-w64-install.exe
2. setup to Version: 6.3.0, Architecture: i686, Threads: posix, Exception: dwarf and Build revision: 2.

I hope this will be of some help.

Comment: Yeah, downgrade is the solution. I used mingw32-8.2.0 and downgraded to mingw-w64-7.1.0

Answer (score 25):

Installing `MinGW` packages `mingw32-libmingwex-*` will link an appropriate version of `vsnprintf` and avoid the linker error.

Comment: It's not a warning; it's a linker error that breaks the build.

Answer (score 11):

This issue, i.e. `multiple definition of vsnprintf`, still exists in [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) as December 2019.

After investigating a lot, I found the solution in the [official mailing list](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/lists/archive/users/2019-August/000335.html).

It's a bug in `mingwrt-5.2.2`. Downgrading to the `mingwrt-5.2.1` version solves that issue.
To do that, just input the following command:

```
mingw-get upgrade mingwrt=5.2.1
```

Then restart the MinGW shell.

[Read the full story here](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/lists/archive/users/2019-August/000337.html).

**Note:** MinGW-w64 and MinGW are separate projects, so the accepted solution is not so helpful to me, as I want to keep MinGW and not to move to MinGW-w64.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple definitions of `vsnprintf` in both `stdio.h` and `libmingwex.a`. I am able to work this around by adding `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0` to the start of the code, before any includes, which disables the definition of `vsnprintf` in `stdio.h`.

Comment: Note that this method means you get a bunch of bugs due to stdio functionality being handed off to MSVCRT