# Mingw Terminal Output: multiple definition of 'vsnprintf'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, printf, mingw

I'm trying to get Mingw to work for VSCode at the moment, I've install all the packages from a Mingw download website and set the bin folder "C:\MinGW\bin" in my Environmental Variables.
I set up a basic "Hello World" single source file and I was able to get the correct output. However now I'm trying to work on a project for school that contains multiple files and when I try to run this code I'm getting the following output in my terminal:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(vsnprintf.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `vsnprintf'; C:\Users\tommy\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA3ybsU.o:equation.cpp:(.text$vsnprintf[_vsnprintf]+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xb0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Not exactly sure how to go about fixing this, if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: If downloading "mingw" make sure you actually get mingw-w64, not mingw.org

Comment: I downloaded the "MinGW-W64-install.exe" from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/

Comment: The message suggests you defined a function called vsnprintf in the `equation.cpp` file . It would improve the question to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MinGW g++: Multiple definition of vsnprintf when using to\_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294488/mingw-g-multiple-definition-of-vsnprintf-when-using-to-string)